# Programar una tarea con SCHTASKS en windows 10

Tags: windows10, task, task-runner

Quiero que mi programa se ejecute cada 5 minutos todos los días, estoy utilizando SCHTASKS. La configuración que hice fue:

**SCHTASKS /SC DAILY /MO 2 /TN prueba /TR C:\Users\unam\Documents\Release\Files\prueba.exe /ST 15:11:00 /SD 18/07/2019**

Pero el error que me aparece es que "ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '/SC'

¿En qué me equivoqué o cuál es la forma correcta de hacer que el programa se ejecute diario, cada 5 minutos?

El error que me sale después de ejecutar el comando corregido es este
[image: Error:]

Y este es el código para leer el archivo, de hecho probé don dos códigos:

```
public static void readData()
{
    //TextReader readFile;
    string chain;
    string fileName = "Datos.txt";
    string fullPath;
string fullPath2= Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,Datos.txt)

    fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);




    //bool found = false;
    string[] fields = new string[2];
    char[] breakUp = { ':' };
    try
    {
                                                        //fullPath2
        using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(fullPath))
        {


            // chain = readFile.ReadLine();



            while ((chain = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                fields = chain.Split(breakUp);
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Te falto definir el /Create y con /SC minute le indicas que sera en minutos, como lo tienes actualmente sera diario cada dos dias.

Prueba con este

```
  SCHTASKS/Create /SC minute /MO 5 /TN prueba /TR C:\Users\unam\Documents\Release\Files\prueba.exe /ST 15:11:00 /SD 18/07/2019
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saludos

Comment: Recuerda lo que te sugerí ayer en otra pregunta. Explica la naturaleza de la solución que propones.

Comment: Me salió el error: 

ERROR: Incorrect Start Date. Ya vi porqué. Ya se creó la tarea,

Comment: SCHTASKS/Create /SC minute /MO 5 /TN prueba /TR C:\Users\unam\Documents\Release\Files\prueba.exe /ST 15:11:00 /SD 18/07/2019
Asi como esta?

Comment: Entonces si funciono? Si te ayudo puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta para asi poder ayudar a otros en un futuro.
Saludos

Comment: No, no funcionó. Pero es problema para encontrar el archivo que requiere leer el programa. Edito la publicación para adjuntar imágenes.

Comment: Ese txt que estas tratando de leer se encuentra en el mismo lugar que tu aplicación?

Comment: Hola! Ya solucioné el problema, era relacionado a la ruta. Sólo una cosa más, esa configuración de la tarea me indica que el programa se ejecutará diario cada 2 minutos INDEFINIDAMENTE o hay que añadirle algo más?

Comment: Como está ahora en la respuesta es cada 5 min indefinidamente es decir cada 5 minutos lo estará haciendo hasta que la detengas o la elimines.
Si quieres que sea cada 2 cambia /MO 5 por /MO 2